# Lógica - Saber se está no segundo dia do mês

Tags: php, data, time

Estou tendo dificuldade para formular uma lógica para saber se o dia que estou é ou não por exemplo o segundo sábado do mês de fevereiro. Com o código que fiz eu consigo pegar o dia que estou, mês e ano, além de percorrer cada dia do mês e parar a execução do `while` se passar o total de dias dos mês.

**Código desenvolvido:**

```
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

    $diasSemanaSigla = array('Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb' );

    $date = date('d-m-Y');

    //echo "Data: ".$date."\n";

    $data = explode('-', $date);
    $dia = $data[0];
    $mes = $data[1];
    $ano = $data[2];

    //echo 'dia: '.$dia.' mes: '.$mes.' ano: '.$ano."\n";

    //echo date( 'w', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano) )."\n";

    $mes = $mes == null ? (int) date('m') : (int) $mes;
    //echo "variavel mes: ".$mes."\n";
    $ano = $ano == null ? date('Y') : $ano;
    //echo "variavel ano: ".$ano."\n";

    $qtdDiasMes = cal_days_in_month( CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);
    //echo "Quantidade dias mes: ".$qtdDiasMes."\n";

    $diasVaziosInicio = date( 'w', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia, $ano) );
    //echo "Dias Vazios inicio: ".$diasVaziosInicio."\n";
    $totalDias = 1;
    while( $qtdDiasMes >= $totalDias ) {
        for( $i = 1; $i <= 7; $i++) {
            if( ($totalDias > $qtdDiasMes)  ) {
                echo "entrou primeiro if"."\n";
                echo "Total dias: ".$totalDias."\n";
                echo "qtdDiasMes: ".$qtdDiasMes."\n";
            } elseif( $diasVaziosInicio != 0 ) {
                echo "entrou segundo if"."\n";
                echo "Dias vazios: ".$diasVaziosInicio."\n";
                $diasVaziosInicio--;
            } else {
                echo "entrou else"."\n";
                echo "Total dias:".$totalDias."\n";
                $totalDias++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir do dia do mês (`date('j')`), você consegue descobrir se ele é o 1º, 2º, ..., nº (Segunda a Sábado) dia do mês. Para isso é necessario dividir o dia do mês por 7 (para ver se completou uma semana). O codigo para isso seria:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$ordem = date('j');

//ceil arredonda uma fração para o maior inteiro mais próximo
//date('D') representa o dia da semana (Mon,Tur,thu,wed,fri,sat,sun)
echo ceil($ordem / 7) . 'º ' . date('D');
```

Ao dividir a variavel `$ordem` por 7, obtem um número fracionario que quando arredondado para cima representa a ordem do dia da semana no mês (se é 1º, 2º, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

```
//primeiro sábado de fevereiro de 2018
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('first saturday of february 2018'));
//segundo sábado de fevereiro de 2018
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('second saturday of february 2018'));
//terceiro 
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('third saturday of february 2018'));
//quarto 
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('fourth saturday of february 2018'));

//quinto sábado - se não houver passa para o próximo mes 
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('fifth saturday of february 2018')); // 03-03-2018
```

[exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/ihEmKA)

> Geral `date('d-m-Y', strtotime('ORDINAL DIA of MES ANO'));`

**Para saber se o dia que estou é ou não o segundo sábado do mês de fevereiro**

```
$segundosabado = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('second saturday of february 2018'));

$hoje = date('d-m-Y');

echo ($hoje == $segundosabado) ? "é" : "não é";
```